# NativeScript-Vue Update Data Object?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is it possible to update a data object with a new property?

The data is coming in from an external source, and justifiably the data does not contain a flag on whether or not to show the contents of the object.

```
<RadListView for="item in list" @itemTap="accordion">
    <v-template>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label :text="item.title" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout v-bind:height="item.toggled? 'auto' : 0">
            <Label :text="item.desc" />
        </StackLayout>
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            list: [
                { "title" : "Sample Title", "desc" : "Lorem Ipsum" },
                { "title" : "New Title", "desc" : "Test 123 Test" }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        accordion: function(e){
            e.item.toggled = !e.item.toggled;
        },
        loadData: function(){ ... },
        generateData: function( data ){ ... }
    }
}
```

So the 'list' objects do not contain a "toggled" property, but I am trying to expand/collapse the "desc" area when a user clicks on an item in the UI.

My code, as is, does return `e.item.toggled` in an expected fashion but the UI does not update
`undefined -> true -> false -> true -> false -> ...`

**UPDATE**:

Going off of @sundeqvist 's suggestion, I passed the `item` element through the method for accordion.

I also modified how the "toggled" property was amended to the data object, "list".  By adding it directly, the console showed the value as a true boolean instead of a Vue [Getter/Setter] value.

```
<RadListView for="item in list">
    <v-template>
        <StackLayout @itemTap="accordion(item)">
            <Label :text="item.title" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout v-bind:height="item.toggled? 'auto' : 0">
            <Label :text="item.desc" />
        </StackLayout>
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            list: [
                { "title" : "Sample Title", "desc" : "Lorem Ipsum" },
                { "title" : "New Title", "desc" : "Test 123 Test" }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        accordion: function(item){
            item.toggled = !item.toggled;
        },
        loadData: function(){ ... },
        generateData: function( data ){
            let dataArr = [];
            for( let d in data ){
                d = { "toggled" : false, ...d };
                dataArr.push( d );
            }
            this.list = dataArr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're accessing `item` in your method?

By passing in `item` into your accordion method call:

`<RadListView for="item in list" @itemTap="accordion(item)">`

and then in your method toggle the `toggle` property on the item you pass in as a parameter:

```
accordion(item) {
  item.toggled = !item.toggled;
}
```

you should be able to get it work.

Comment: I think you got me going the right way (although) I'm uncertain if it's THE right way -- I moved the `@itemTap="accordion(item)"` down to the StackLayout element -- and where the code ingests the external data, instead of assigning a property to the object, I did a spread `{"toggled" : false, ...data}` -- that then turned "toggled" into the vue [getter/setter]

Comment: It looks like it's working, but the console makes it looks like it's triggering a total re-draw?

Comment: A redraw of the whole array? Sounds weird... Have you solved it? If you could throw up a codepen I could check it out!